# Django2.0.7 TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to migrate the models that were generated for me via `python manage.py inspectdb`. I tried `python manage.py makemigrations` and got this error:

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>   ERRORS:
>   Users.DjangoContentType: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.

So I went into my file and changed this model:
[image]

To this:
[image]

and when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` and I get this error:

[image]

Any idea what I should do/what this means?

This is my pip freeze output:

```
certifi==2018.10.15
Django==2.0.7
mysqlclient==1.3.13
pytz==2018.7
```

Comment: just remove the `id` field from your model. because its already present and its primary key

Comment: Then I get this error: `TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable`

Comment: Why are you including DjangoContentType as part of your models? I’m quite sure you shouldn't as it is part of the content_types application

Comment: The ContentType model is used by Django to track the models in te installed apps in a Django project. It is automatically populated by Django and you should not need to mess around with it in most cases

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: @ivissani when I initially did `python inspectdb` and then `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`, I got this error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydb.django_content_type' doesn't exist")` so I manually added the table to my database;

Comment: There is not enough information but still notice that you should run migrate command before running makemigrations (and then running migrate again) precisely to instruct Django to create all the tables that it needs . On the other hand if you are leaving all your generated models as unmanaged you do not need to run makemigrations command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dropped my database and reinitialized it, and all the steps that I initially took worked... somehow. Still can't explain why

Answer (score 0):

ID is an implicitly declared field in django. You dont need to add it in list of model fields. Django autogenerates ID for you.

> An id field is added automatically, but this behavior can be overridden. See Automatic primary key fields.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/

Comment: yes, but when I remove those fields and get this error: `TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable`

Comment: Is there an already existing table in your db called django_content_type ? Which DB you are using ? I think you shouldn''t be using managed=False if there is no existing table that you want to manage.

Comment: I'm using mysql, and when I initially did `python inspectdb` and then `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`, I got this error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydb.django_content_type' doesn't exist")` so I manually added the table to my database;

Comment: Please delete all the tables, remove meta classes, Run migrations using 

`python manage.py migrate <appname>`

See what error it is giving